# How to download bert models and load in python?

Tags: python, nlp, bert-language-model, sentence-transformers

How to download bert models and load in python?

```py
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
model = SentenceTransformer('bert-base-nli-mean-tokens')
```

**How to save the pretrained model and load in python?**

Comment: Is there an error message with the way you are currently doing it? Once you are executing the second line, your models are automatically stored offline. If you want to store fine-tuned models, then this is a different question altogether.

Comment: We can just do model.save('file_path') This is working..